Is it OK to post a question about a Q&A which is already answered & accepted?
I have posted a question & accepted an answer for the question.
After some days & more study on the topic, I feel that the answer is not convincing enough & I suspect it may be wrong. I wish for the question to be answered again.
What is the best thing to do here? Should I post a new question linking the older question & also give reasons as to why I think that my accepted answer may not be right?
I am posting this question here instead of in main meta site because I think right & wrong answers are more objective is SE site like crypto than it would be in general SE sites.

If the original answer is really lacking, an option is to move some of it in the original question (at the end, after some update: notice), explaining what's wrong with that; and flag that lacking answer to moderator attention, asking that it be deleted.
I the original answer can stay, the simplest is to make another question restating the problem, and why the original answer doesn't cut it.
Both will bring the modified or new question on top of the active questions.
